# Showing DataTable output of multiple dependent selectInputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having finding trouble showing the output related to my selectInput selectors. I made two dependent selectInput selectors: *Location* and *Year*. What I want, is to show the corresponding selection of my data frame, using dataTableOutput.

For example, choosing Location "2" and Year "2016" shows the records of Katy and William.

This is my simplified **ui** section:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Location = c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3") 
Year = c(2015,2014,2016,2015,2016,2016,2017,2016,2014) 
Person = c("John", "Ann", "Katy", "Ann", "Katy", "William", "Henry", "Luke", "Luke")
mockup = data.frame(Location, Year, Person)

ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Selection", tabName = "selection")                  
                                  )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "selection",
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(width = 5, 
                                      title = "TITLE", "Choose something",
                                      collapsible = FALSE, 
                                      htmlOutput("Location_selector"),
                                      htmlOutput("Year_selector")
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    DT::dataTableOutput("selection")
                                  )
                                 ))             

                                        )
                      )
                      )
```

and this is my **server** section:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Location_selector = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Location",
                label = "Location:",
                choices = as.character(unique(mockup$Location)))
  })
  output$Year_selector = renderUI({

    data_available = mockup[mockup$Location == input$Location, "Year"]

    selectInput(inputId = "Year",
                label = "Year:",
                choices = unique(data_available),
                selected = unique(data_available)[1])
  })

  output$selection <-  DT::renderDataTable({

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know I am missing stuff regarding the next part, but I am unable resolving this so far:

```
output$selection <-  DT::renderDataTable({

    })
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `with(mockup, mockup[Year==input$Year & Location==input$Location,])`?

Comment: You could try `subset(mockup, Location == input$Location & Year == input$Year)`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. Works fine. Thanks a lot! EDIT: subset also does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both suggestions worked:

```
subset(mockup, Location == input$Location & Year == input$Year)
```

and

```
with(mockup, mockup[Year==input$Year & Location==input$Location,])
```